# .htaccess redirect everything except certain request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, regex, .htaccess

I am having an issue with my `.htaccess` file. It is redirecting everything through my `index.php` page which is what I want for the majority of requests.

***BUT the only time I do not want to redirect is via an AJAX call.***

It redirects any request through my `index.php` file like so:
`RewriteRule /.* /index.php [NC,L]`

The AJAX request url is:
`http://myurl.dev/login/ajax/functions.php`

With the directory structure:
`/modules/login/ajax/functions.php`

I am inexperienced with regex and RewriteRules, and have read / tried many variations with varying logic but cannot stop anything from **/ajax/** to not redirect to the index page.

I have tried a RewriteCond before the Index RewriteRule to redirect to index unless **/ajax/** but no luck.

```
Rewrite Cond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/ajax
RewriteRule /.* /index.php [NC,L]
```

Also tried a seperate RewriteRule for the /ajax/ request:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/ajax/functions\.php$ /modules/$1/ajax/functions.php [NC,L]`

So nothing as worked so far, it either redirects to the `index` or hits a `500 server error`.

Does anybody have any suggestions or links to help? Thanks.

**Note**: When I say redirect, I do not mean a full page refresh as I know that Apache wont do a full url refresh without the *[R]* flag.

### -- Edit: Working file --

Here is my full .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on

# Intercept any requests to the core, and keep them being written to the core (so they don't go to index.php)
RewriteRule ^core/(.*)$ core/$1 [NC,L]

# The magic, stops any requests to a file for being redirected.
# needed to be under the /core/ redirect
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

# Rewrite all requests to index.php.
RewriteRule /.* /index.php [NC,L]

# Some requests (without trailing slashes) can fall through the above rule. This bit catches those stragglers.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 /404/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d //excludes existing directories
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f //excludes existing files
```

before any `RewriteRule` . This will exclude any directory or file which already exists, so the `RewriteRule` won't work on `http://myurl.dev/login/ajax/functions.php`, because it actually exists, but it will work on `http://myurl.dev/someOtherNonExistantFile.php`

That makes this your full .htaccess file code:

```
AuthType Basic
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
# Intercept any requests to the core, and keep them being written to the core (so they don't go to index.php)
RewriteRule ^core/(.*)$ core/$1 [NC,L]

# Rewrite all requests to index.php.
RewriteRule /.* /index.php [NC,L]

# Some requests (without trailing slashes) can fall through the above rule. This bit catches those stragglers.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 /404/
```

Comment: Good idea, just tried that however the /core/ redirection is needed for php classes, css and js files. And due to the `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f` it's not properly redirecting to these files and therefore getting 404 loading these files. I Moved this RewriteCond below the /core/ RewriteRule and all the files load properly and now the redirect is working properly. Thanks! Updated question with working file.